# Using Sass for dynamic colors

Tags: css

```
.brown,.blue,.pink,.orange,.red,.yellow,.green,.navy,.taxes {
display:block;
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-weight:700;
background:#000;/*<--- the color of this should be brown, blue, pink etc*/
color:#fff;
width:100%;
}
.brown{
background: brown;
}
```

At the moment this is hoow I am achieving this effect. My question is: what is the most efficient way of achieving this effect? In SASS i could do this but I would still have to write 6 different variables for each color, so not sure how that is any more efficient.

Also to note that I am using class names instead of id names because each color has multiple instances, there are 2 browns, 3 blues, 3 pinks. So is my usage of classes correct, as id should be really used for unique values?

Comment: If you built your website with these class, you need to keep going ... .orange{
background: orange;
}

Comment: I believe this is the only way of doing it without javascript

Comment: To be honest, what you are doing is a terrible way of coding. Everything need to be manageable via the Css and not directly inside the Html

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes I did with js first, but there is little difference in terms of lines of code. so I guess I will just continue with simple css then.

Comment: @Romain I am not sure I follow. This is for a monopoly game, and `.brown` for instance represents the brown set, it is a span. In CSS i just change the color, so I am not sure why it is terrible way of coding? Please explain, I want to do things the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't advise coding your CSS that way, but you could make a list then for loop through it.
For example:

SASS

```
$colorList:
    "white" #fff,
    "grey" #ccc
;

@each $i in $colorList {
    .color-#{nth($i,1)} {
         background-color: nth($i,2);
    }
}
```

Output CSS

```
.color-grey {
   background-color: #ccc;
}

.color-white {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Right I think this is what I need. I will play with this code, might take me a long while. Im new to SASS. Coudle you explain this line `.color-#{nth($i,1)}`

Comment: [This](http://jeffvincent.me/using-sass-hashes) will give you a much better explanation than I can put in a comment

Comment: I got it to work now and thanks Martin I will have a look at that.